# about the difference between newtwork graph using Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

I would like to know the difference between Fruchterman-Rheingold, prefuse force directed layout using weight, edge-weighted force directed layout(Bio), and Edge-weighted Spring embedding.

I would like to reflect the weights of edge as network graph. Which one is best?
Fruchterman-Rheingold is not a default option, right?

Prefuse force directed layout using weight and edge-weighted Spring embedding make sense based on heatmap results of affinity matrix, but edge-weighted force directed layout(Bio)looks strange.....

I would deeply appreciate it if you could explain and tell which one is best.

Answer (score 0):

There is honestly no "best" layout for edge-weighted graphs.  BioLayout is an implementation of the Fruchterman-Rheingold algorightm and "Spring embedded" is Kamada-Kawai.  Prefuse force directed is probably the fasted of all of the algorithms since it uses a pretty fast integrator.  My suggestion is to use all of them (don't forget to use the Layout Settings dialog to tune them) and then choose the one that gives you the best results.

-- scooter